# Why are some commands in cmder not found?

Tags: cmder

Example when I use the command (m) to display the contents of the file, I get a message " 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command. "
There are also other commands, such as a cat and rm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the same thing was happining to me until i downloaded the full version, download the full version not the lite/mini version.